# C/ Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCD

Tags: c

I have a problem when reading the first decimal value from the file;it throws me an error and i can't possibly imagine why.any ideas are welcome.thanks for any help

```
struct Cuvant{
char *valoare;
char descriere[100];
int nr;
int *poz;};

Cuvant* readFile(char *fisier){
FILE *pFILE = fopen(fisier, "r");
Cuvant *vector = NULL;
if (pFILE){
    char buffer[100];
    int buff[100];
    int i = 0;

    while (!feof(pFILE))
    {
        vector = (Cuvant*)malloc(sizeof(Cuvant));

        fscanf(pFILE, "%s", buffer);
        vector[i].valoare = new char[strlen(buffer)+1];
        strcpy(vector[i].valoare, buffer);

        char buffer2[100];
        fscanf(pFILE, "%s", buffer2);
        strcpy(vector[i].descriere, buffer2);


        fscanf(pFILE, "%d", vector[i].nr);

        vector[i].poz = new int[vector[i].nr];
        for (int j = 0; j < vector[i].nr; j++)
            fscanf(pFILE, "%d", vector[i].poz[j]);

        i++;

    }
}
return vector;}
```

Comment: after a quick look, it seems that your vector is not a vector, but a single struct Cuvant, there's something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
fscanf(pFILE, "%d", vector[i].nr);
```

and

```
fscanf(pFILE, "%d", vector[i].poz[j]);
```

should be:

```
fscanf(pFILE, "%d", &(vector[i].nr));
```

and

```
fscanf(pFILE, "%d", &(vector[i].poz[j]));
```

Also, you only allocate a single Cuvant structure, but then try to index it as if it were an array.

Answer (score 0):

A few considerations:
You allocate memory for a single Cuvant struct, and then you use access different indexes of that element, as it was not allocated as an array doesn't make sense to access as an array.

Other point: You're allocating memory in any iteration of a loop, it can be expensive, and lead to memory leaks, after the end of a iteration you allocate memory again for the same variable, what happens is that you lose any reference to the memory allocated in the previous iteration, it creates memory leak as you don't have a way to claim the memory again.

Finally, the fscanf documentation says:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/

> int fscanf ( FILE * stream, const char * format, ... ); Read formatted
>   data from stream Reads data from the stream and stores them according
>   to the parameter format into the locations pointed by the additional
>   arguments.
>
> The additional arguments should point to already allocated objects of
>   the type specified by their corresponding format specifier within the
>   format string.

That means you additional parameters should be pointers, you can pass an address of your variable, so this way fscanf can write in your variable, otherwise it can't.
So you can add the address operaor & before your variables.

```
vector = (Cuvant*)malloc(sizeof(Cuvant)*vector_size);
while (!feof(pFILE))
{
    fscanf(pFILE, "%s", buffer);
    vector[i].valoare = new char[strlen(buffer)+1];
    strcpy(vector[i].valoare, buffer);

    char buffer2[100];
    fscanf(pFILE, "%s", buffer2);
    strcpy(vector[i].descriere, buffer2);


    fscanf(pFILE, "%d", &(vector[i].nr));

    vector[i].poz = malloc(vector[i].nr*sizeof(int));
    for (int j = 0; j < vector[i].nr; j++)
        fscanf(pFILE, "%d", &(vector[i].poz[j]));

    i++;

}
```

PS: You're mixing C++/C code (like using **malloc** and **new** in the same code) which can lead to errors and is a bad practice.